# Qualquer url abre no webview?

Tags: android, webview

Tenho minha função:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("http://www.hotelcolonialdosnobres.com/")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }return false:
}
```

Porem eu queria que somente o meu site abrisse no webview o restante abrisse no navegador normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente assim ó:

```
public class WebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {
    private Activity activity = null;
    public WebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
       this.activity = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        if(url.indexOf("hotelcolonialdosnobres.com") > -1 )
            return false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, se na url contem teu site, shouldOverrideUrlLoading retorna false e retorna para a chamada do webview.

dai voce chama ele assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.hotelcolonialdosnobres.com/");
    }
}
```

Note que para instanciar o WebViewClientImpl é passada a mesma activity "**new WebViewClientImpl(this);**" como parametro.

para saber mais sobre isso, acesse [Jakob Jenkov tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html#calling-javascript-via-webview-loadurl) que foi de onde tirei a referencia.

espero que ajude!